# Installing MacPorts as a non-superuser

Tags: macports

Is it possible to install MacPorts as a non-superuser?  I install applications to ~/Applications/ and they run fine.  I'd like to install an instance of MacPorts to ~/opt/local/, and have everything that I run under this account link to that instance.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Macports website documents this procedure in their installation guide:
https://trac.macports.org/wiki/InstallingMacPorts

Comment: Link is now broken. Is there a guide somewhere else?